# Shouldn't online users counts only for specific site (ITS in this case)?

Tags: discussion, chat

http://phpcode.eu/images/1314811981.png

Shouldn't it say "7 People Chatting"? Because 80 people are in whole StackExchange chat, not in specific room

Answer (score 3):

It says 80 chatting then it specifically shows the DMZ with the 7 in it because you are currently on security.stackexchange. If you were on bicycles.stackexchange.com it would show the folks in chat there.

This is by design.